# MySQL go through array of values and return every row with match

Tags: javascript, mysql

Say I have an array with IDs:

**values = [0, 43, 5]**

Now I want to go through my table "tbl_EVENTS"
and return every row where EVENTID = 0, 43, or 5.

Every ID will only appear once. So I could technically do three different queries.

I am working with a `javascript` frameworks that builds an SQL string in the end, so I could wrap this into a for loop if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you are looking for:

If your `values = [0, 43, 5]` an array then, we can use join method with template literals.

```
const values = [0, 43, 5];
`SELECT * FROM tbl_EVENTS WHERE EVENTID IN(${values.join(',')})`
```

Comment: Thank you. But this isnt dynamic enough. I dont know the arrays length at first...

Comment: Updated my answer. No need to know the length of the array.

Comment: We are using template literals ( backticks ) here to concatenate the query and our spread.

Comment: Here is my syntax: 

var arrObject = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < eventIdResults.length; i++) {
  arrObject.push(eventIdResults.itemAtIndex(i).tblEventID)
}

var string = "SELECT * FROM 10561_12865_tblEvents WHERE tblEventID IN(${arrObject.join(',')})"
var res = K.query(string,[]);

But it fails. Stating that I have an error in my syntax "near arrObject.join(',')"

Comment: ` "SELECT * FROM 10561_12865_tblEvents WHERE tblEventID IN(${arrObject.join(',')})"` Wrap this in backticks not double quotes

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed that once I put it into backticks, the arrObject changes its color, so the framework regocnizes it as a variable. hoever, my debugger returns "illegal character". So appearantly, in this case, I cannot use backticks. Is there another option? Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236183/discussion-between-rakesh-k-and-innom).